# How to set height of a Ext JS grid.Grid's headercontainer?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, sencha-touch, extjs6

I want to set and fix height of headercontainer in my grid.
Whitch configs to do it? `header:` config for grid.Grid does not exist
Now it look like a bag: 
[image: how to manage of headercontainer of grid height?]

Comment: You can do some adjustment with css, but that gap is not supposed to happen, check your grid declaration

Comment: in firefox browser it renters good (without gap). And when I do some manipulation with padding/marging in the developer dashboard Chromium gap is desapears, but after sort click on column header gap shows again... grid class was defined very simple, like on sencha example

Comment: Which is it? Ext 4? Ext 6? Or Sencha Touch?

Comment: it is Ext js 6.2, modern toolkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ExtJS 6 classic you can do something like this:

```
listeners:{
      'afterrender': function(g){
          var d = g.getHeaderContainer();
          d.setHeight(50);
      }  
    },
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2ovs